# naturalWidth and naturalHeight returns 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, event-handling, dom-events

I have a code that checks the ratio of images. It works 9 out of 10 times or even more but once in a while it doesn't work because img.naturalWidth and img.naturalHeight returns 0. I can understand that the image is not loaded at that moment when I am trying to fetch the height and width of image but I am clueless why it happens rarely. The code is also inside reader.onload which is the solution I found in most of the online articles.

```
isValidFileRatio(selectedFile: Blob, width: number, height: number): any {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  const img = new Image();
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);

  reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
  reader.onload = () => {
    const ratio = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight;
    
    resolve(ratio >= 1 && ratio <= 2);
  };
  reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
});
```

}

Any solution or suggestion appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `new FileReader()` is useless and it has caused this bug. Change your code like this:

```
isValidFileRatio(selectedFile: Blob, width: number, height: number): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
        
        img.onload = () => {
            const ratio = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight;

            resolve(ratio >= 1 && ratio <= 2);
        };
        img.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `filereader.onload` instead of `image.onload`

Here is how i would have solved it:

I would have used `createImageBitmap`, instead of using `FileReader`, `Image`, or `Canvas` that would require a mix of callbacks and promises.

I also tend to break out of promise chain when possible by making most of my own code sync. that way my own function dose not become async b/c something else is async.

```js
/**
 * @param {{ width: number, height: number }} image
 */
function isValidFileRatio (image) {
  const ratio = image.width / image.height
  return ratio >= 1 && ratio <= 2
}

// Just to get a simple dummy image/png blob for demo
var blob = new OffscreenCanvas(300, 200).getContext('2d').canvas.convertToBlob()

blob
  .then(createImageBitmap)
  .then(isValidFileRatio)
  .then(console.log)
```